# parametrized selector in ngrx has type unknown

Tags: redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have a `ngrx/entity` store where I would like to select all entity using a parameter and draw it in a table.

I made the following selector

```
export const selectByAdvertiserId = () =>
  createSelector(selectAllUsers, (users: Array<EntityUser>, props: { advertiserId: string }) =>
    users.filter((u) => u.advertiserId === props.advertiserId)
  )
```

And use it like this

```
  connect() {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(selectByAdvertiserId(), { advertiserId: this.advertiser?.id }),
      map((res) => res || [])
    )
  }
```

The problem is connect should return a `Observable<EntityUser[]>` and the current implementation **at compile time only** return me the following error :

> Property 'connect' in type 'AdvertisersUsersListComponent' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'DataSource'.
> Type '() => Observable' is not assignable to type '(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer) => Observable<EntityUser[] | readonly EntityUser[]>'.
> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable<EntityUser[] | readonly EntityUser[]>'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'EntityUser[] | readonly EntityUser[]'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'readonly EntityUser[]'.

but I don't get what is type unknown

I changed to

```
export const selectByAdvertiserId2 = createSelector(
  selectAllUsers,
  (users) => (advertiserId: string) => users.filter((u) => u.advertiserId === advertiserId)
)
```

```
  connect() {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(selectByAdvertiserId),
      map((res) => res(this.advertiser?.id || '') || [])
    )
  }
```

And this has the correct type, buyt I do not like the fact that it's a function that is returned. How would I fix my case 1 ?

Comment: I also tried to use `as Observable<EntityUser[]>`

Comment: can u provide to an stackblitz demo?